# A bug of AccessibilityManagerService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Bug Des:

a variable `mBindingSerivce` in UserState.java has not cleared after fail start Accessibility Service

`mBindingSerivce` means a Accessibility Service set of being started

```java
 @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mService != service) {
                if (mService != null) {
                    mService.unlinkToDeath(this, 0);
                }
                mService = service;
                try {
                   // start Accessibility Service
                    mService.linkToDeath(this, 0);
                } catch (RemoteException re) {
                   // fail start Accessibility Service, will run binderDied()
                    Slog.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed registering death link");
                    binderDied();
                   // will directly return
                    return;
                }
            }
            mServiceInterface = IAccessibilityServiceClient.Stub.asInterface(service);
            UserState userState = mUserStateWeakReference.get();
            if (userState == null) return;
            userState.addServiceLocked(this);
            mSystemSupport.onClientChangeLocked(false);
            // Initialize the service on the main handler after we're done setting up for
            // the new configuration (for example, initializing the input filter).
            mMainHandler.sendMessage(obtainMessage(
                    AccessibilityServiceConnection::initializeService, this));
        }
    }

 public void binderDied() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            // It is possible that this service's package was force stopped during
            // whose handling the death recipient is unlinked and still get a call
            // on binderDied since the call was made before we unlink but was
            // waiting on the lock we held during the force stop handling.
            if (!isConnectedLocked()) {
                return;
            }
            mWasConnectedAndDied = true;
            UserState userState = mUserStateWeakReference.get();
            if (userState != null) {
                userState.serviceDisconnectedLocked(this);
            }
            resetLocked();
            mSystemSupport.getMagnificationController().resetAllIfNeeded(mId);
            mSystemSupport.onClientChangeLocked(false);
        }
    }
```

so when restart Service, the code will run. please see `1` comment.

```java
private void updateServicesLocked(UserState userState) {
        // ...
        for (int i = 0, count = userState.mInstalledServices.size(); i < count; i++) {
            AccessibilityServiceInfo installedService = userState.mInstalledServices.get(i);
            ComponentName componentName = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(
                    installedService.getId());

            AccessibilityServiceConnection service = componentNameToServiceMap.get(componentName);

            // Ignore non-encryption-aware services until user is unlocked
            if (!isUnlockingOrUnlocked && !installedService.isDirectBootAware()) {
                Slog.d(LOG_TAG, "Ignoring non-encryption-aware service " + componentName);
                continue;
            }

            // 1. will run return due to mBindingService have not cleared
            if (userState.mBindingServices.contains(componentName)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (userState.mEnabledServices.contains(componentName)
                    && !mUiAutomationManager.suppressingAccessibilityServicesLocked()) {
                if (service == null) {
                    service = new AccessibilityServiceConnection(userState, mContext, componentName,
                            installedService, sIdCounter++, mMainHandler, mLock, mSecurityPolicy,
                            this, mWindowManagerService, mGlobalActionPerformer);
                } else if (userState.mBoundServices.contains(service)) {
                    continue;
                }
                service.bindLocked();
            } else {
                if (service != null) {
                    service.unbindLocked();
                }
            }
        }

       //...
    }
```

this will cause forever can't successful start service expect to restart AccessibilityManagerService

Comment: Hi!  If you have a bug to report in Android, take a look at https://b.android.com/ - it'll tell you exactly how to file a bug report in the issue tracker to get it looked at.

Comment: Thanks,  i had summited this question